# How to set out css properly?

Tags: css, wrapper

Hey could someone tell me if this part of my css is right or wrong?

I personally think it is wrong but this is the only way I can place content in the center of the screen, if I replace the `999px` with `auto` everything goes to the left.

If anyone knows how to write it properly that would be great!

I have been making website for quite a while now but I need to learn the right way.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/prQXJ/)**

Comment: Can u show me live example in jsfiddle.net  ...........

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Is it possible for you to add thois code along with your HTML markup into an example at www.jsfiddle.net? This would help us a lot to visualize your problem and provide a working solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that `#wrapper` stay in the center of your page your code is correct.

You can specify every width you want, but not `auto`.

---

If you are looking for **Responsive Design**, take a look at the `@Media Queries`

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/responsive-design-harnessing-power-of.html

---

Example:

Write your css for normal style, then add:

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Here you can specify different size and style for browser with that min or max size.

A good tool for start using Responsive Design is: **[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)**

Comment: But say a device is bigger that 999px or smaller, how would I go about that then? Everything would mess up right?

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example please?

Comment: Thank you Andrea I will look through this now :)